# Is it possible to find the inverse of the following function explicitly?

Tags: continuity, inverse, inverse-function, inverse-function-theorem

I am interested in the following function

$$
f(x) = \sqrt{3x \left(1-\frac{x}{\theta} \right) \ln{\left[a \left(1-\frac{\theta}{x} \right)  \right]}},   
$$

with $ 0<a \leq 1$ and $\theta<x$. Now to make things simple, assume $a= \theta = 1$.

The function seems complicated to be able to find its inverse directly, however is there a way to get maybe an expansion of its inverse? Some sort of infinite series maybe? I used desmos to [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvvBc.png) both the function (red) and its inverse (green), just to get an idea of its shape.

Thanks.

Comment: You want the inverse of $\sqrt{3x (1-x ) \ln\left(1-\frac1{x} \right)} $?

Comment: Yes, for simplicity we assume 'a' and theta are 1. Even in this simpler case, is it possible to find some sort of an expression?

Comment: If $x=\frac1{1-e^w},$ then we need to solve $x(1-x)\ln(1-\frac1x)=a\iff \cosh(w)+\frac w{2a}=1$, a [Kepler equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) or $w=-ae^{-w}(e^w-1)^2$ where [Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) could maybe be used.

Comment: Interesting to know that this essentially becomes the kepler equation. Thanks for spotting that!

Comment: If you consider that this is a valid solution, may be you could accept it. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\theta t$ and consider
$$\frac{f^2(x)}{3\theta}=(1-t)\,t\, \log \left(a\frac{ t-1}{t}\right)=y$$

Expand for large values of $t$ to get
$$y=- \log (a)t^2+ (1+\log (a))t-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6
   t}-\frac{1}{12 t^2}-\frac{1}{20
   t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^4}\right)$$ Using power series reversion
$$t=z+\frac{\log (a)+1}{2 \log (a)}+\frac{\log ^2(a)+1}{8 z \log
   ^2(a)}-\frac{1}{12 z^2 \log
   (a)}+O\left(\frac{1}{z^3}\right)$$ where $z=\sqrt{-\frac{y}{\log (a)}}$

Trying for $y=100$ and $a=\frac 1e$ gives $t=\frac{12031}{1200}=10.0258$ while the "exact" solution is $\cdots$ the same.

**Edit**

If $a=1$, the result is
$$t=y+\frac 12+\frac 1{6y}\left(1-\frac{7}{60 y^2}+\frac{139}{5040 y^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{y^6}\right)   \right)$$  For $y=100$, this gives $t=100.502$ while the "exact" solution is $\cdots$ the same.

Using this expression and expanding again for large values of $y$
$$\text{lhs - rhs}\sim \frac 1{734 \, y^7}$$

Comment: Thanks! This works :)